# why does the spinner on my tab in chrome never stop spinning?

Tags: google-chrome

I was developing a website and the spinner on the tab in chrome would not stop spinning.

I donot want to show the website to users with the spinner constantly revolving.

I have disabled the cache while dev tools are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by emptying the cache and doing a hard reload.

[image: how to empty cahce]